# Unsual sizes of TFT, LCD or OLED panels?

Tags: lcd, tft

On Stackoverflow there was a question about a round TFT display, but that answer was difficult and pricey.

What is the possibility of finding rectangular LCD/TFT/OLED displays that are small in height, or long in width? Like a LED strip banner display, but then in either color or monochrome. Like one third the height of a normal 16:9 monitor. So 16:3.

Comment: Where is this question?

Comment: Product recommendations will get closed here.  I reworded your question so that it could stand alone.

Comment: BTW, Japan display does a circular display for the pebble watch so , it is neither pricey or difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In short No, there are some companies that provide smaller displays for wearables and small electronics displays, but those are standard sizes , like electronic shelf labels etc.

For larger displays, there is no demand and as such the cost of the NRE of first runs are so high that there is *ZERO* reason to do this.

If you do need such displays *and* have the $$ then there are cool companies that can take also any display and cut it down to size.  Of course they can only cut to modulo driver chip size (i.e. they have to cut between driver chip lines) but they can do it. One such company is http://pixelscientific.com/

Answer (score 0):

A little something I want to add: some display technology allows for borderless displays. You can combine several of those borderless displays to make what is effectively one big display. Although this does mean that your controller chip can churn out that many pixels fast enough (so something with a proper GPU may be called for, like a nVidia Tegra which comes with an onboard GeForce GPU)

Answer (score 0):

When designing in a TFT displays, go with a standard. The cost to tool up a custom TFT to meet your needs of one that is short and long is reallllly high. Like $200K or more just for the tooling. Try to go with a standard size TFT or switch to a monochrome.